# Как сделать функцию в Python, которая устанавливает в папку видео из тиктока, имея на него ссылку?

Tags: python, instagram, instagram-api

Как сделать функцию в Python, которая устанавливает в папку видео из тиктока, имея на него ссылку?

Я пытался сам, но ничего не получается.

Answer (score 0):

Get the video URL from the web...

Go to this URL and find a video you like https://www.tiktok.com/en/trending
Click the video you want to watch
Copy and paste the URL that is in your web browser
then run

python tiktok-dl.py --output out.mp4 --verbose VIDEO_URL_HERE
There is an example in test.bat

Посмотри здесь - https://github.com/tonetheman/tiktok-dl

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: переведите, пожалуйста, текст ответа (нажав [edit] ниже текста ответа) на русский язык